# Warnings in syslog

Tags: syslog

Syslog displays these warnings and **I would like to know how I can find out what they mean in order to search for what can I do about them.**

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog| grep -i 'warn'
Nov 27 13:48:19 pc NetworkManager[781]: <warn> bluez error getting default adapter: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
Nov 27 13:48:19 pc gdm-binary[778]: WARNING: Unable to find users: no seat-id found
Nov 27 13:48:20 pc NetworkManager[781]: <warn> bluez error getting default adapter: No such adapter
Nov 27 13:48:24 pc gdm-simple-greeter[1285]: Gtk-WARNING: /build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.24.4/gtk/gtkwidget.c:5687: widget not within a GtkWindow
```

**Edit:** The question is about how to interpret warnings like this, and not about my wifi.

Comment: Are you having a problem with your system? It is normal to have warning messages in syslog. Unless you have problems with the listed items, just ignore them.

Comment: Yes, sometimes I have some. What are the warning for anyway? Do they have any meaning? That is what I am asking for. Moreover, I have seen that often, Linux installations write repeatedly logs and logs and logs about little things with little or no importance. But to stop the continuous writing of those log lines and the activity they are logging can be important to save disk and decrease unnecessary activity.

Comment: I have problems because sometimes the wifi connectio gets lost. The wifi deconfigured, it does not appear in ifconfig, and I can put it up but I cannot recover the normal use of the device until I reboot, among other little problems.

Comment: Your wi-fi problem would be suitable for another question, either here or on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/).

Answer (score 4):

- Line 1 and line 3 are related to `bluez`, which manages Bluetooth. Judging by the line `bluez error getting default adapter: No such adapter`, it sounds like your computer doesn't even have a Bluetooth adapter, so this should be harmless. I doubt it's related to your wifi issues.
- I'm not sure about line 2, but it seems to be harmless (in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/433928) someone said "the GDM warning is a red-herring and causes no other symptoms"; "I get the seat-id error, but my GDM is working fine, so I think it is unrelated.")
- Line 4 is a harmless warning message in a GTK+ program. [Carpetsmoker on the FreeBSD forum said](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=14974), "This is a warning and not an error, this is actually a programming fault and not a configuration fault. Ignore it."

  I believe just means the programmer was lazy and [forgot to call a utility function in the GUI toolkit](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/PyGTK.html):

  > ```
  > # Place after association to hbox/vbox to avoid the following error:
  > # GtkWarning: gtkwidget.c:5460: widget not within a GtkWindow
  > button_close.grab_default()
  > ```